# Telescoping trigonometric series: $\sin(x) \sec(3x) + \cdots+ \sin(3^{n}x) \sec(3^{n+1} x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you evaluate the sum of this series:

$$\sin(x) \sec(3x) + \sin(3x) \sec(3^{2}x) + \sin(3^{2}x) \sec(3^{3} x) + \cdots+ \sin(3^{n}x) \sec(3^{n+1} x)$$

I can tell it is a telescoping series but I am not able to get that one step that will cancel all terms

Comment: Can you be more clear about the series? ie $\sin(x) \sec(3x) + \sin(3x) \sec^{2}(3x) + \cdots$ or $\sin(x) \sec(3x) + \sin(3x) \sec(3^{2}x) + \sin(3^{2}x) \sec(3^{3} x) + \cdots$

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin(3y-y)}{\cos3y\cos y}=\tan3y-\tan y$$

and $$\frac{\sin(3y-y)}{\cos3y\cos y}=\frac{\sin2y}{\cos3y\cos y}=\frac{2\sin y\cos y}{\cos3y\cos y}=2\frac{\sin y}{\cos3y}$$ if $\cos y\ne0$

Set $\displaystyle y=x,3x,3^2x\cdots$ to recognize the telescoping Series

Comment: @user34304, How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Lab Bhattacharjee has provided the necessary components to evaluate the series.
The series is seen as:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{ \sin(3^{k} x) }{ \cos(3^{k+1} x)} &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( \tan(3^{k+1} x) - \tan(3^{k} x) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \tan( 3^{n+1} x) - \tan(x) \right).
\end{align}